# Is it correct to say "big kind hands"?

Tags: meaning, adjectives

Is the arrangement of adjective correct in the sentence below?

> The man’s face was in a shade when **big kind hands** lifted me up and held me.

Also, is the sentence easy to understand? (The man with a face in shade is also the man that lifts the narrator up.)

Comment: You can't let "a shade" stand alone like that, it needs it's colour: "a shade of grey/purple/etc.", maybe you meant "The man's face was hidden in shadow"? As for your _big kind hands_ they're perfectly fine. Also thanks for asking this question, made me remember my favourite quote from the Never Ending Story: "They look like big strong hands, don't they?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what you're trying to say. The best way to write your sentence is this:

> The man's face was in **the** shade when **his** big, kind hands lifted me up and held me.

The arrangement of adjectives is correct, however you missed a few things:

1. *A shade* doesn't make sense because *shade* by itself doesn't refer to a specific part of shade, but instead shade as a whole — **the** shade.
2. Since you want to attribute the hands to the man who has the hands, you simply need to insert *his*. Now the reader understands that *his hands* is referring back to the man mentioned earlier.
3. A comma goes between the two adjectives describing the man's hands because both adjectives are modifying *hands* in an equal way ([this](http://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/commas-with-adjectives) article clarifies it a little bit).

After making these changes, the sentence is golden.